# Não consigo realizar conversão de cor apos rotacionar imagem

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo que rotaciona imagens de 10 em 10 graus. Para isso, eu estou identificando o centro da minha regiao de interesse, e nao o centro da imagem, pois tem regiao de interesse que estao proximo dos cantos. Com isso eu consigo rotacionar cada imagem centralizada, mantendo as dimensões originais da imagem. O problema que estou tendo é, que ao identificar o centro da imagem, eu converto a imagem de entrada em escala de cinza, com isso, nao consigo converter a imagem pos rotacionada para a cor 'original'.

Segue codigo abaixo:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

POS_ROT_STEP = 18
IMG = 'IMG006'

img = cv2.imread(IMG+'.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,2,1)
cnt = contours

for i in range (len(cnt)):
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[i])
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    print ('Circle: ' + str(i) + ' - Center: ' + str(center) + ' - Radius: ' + str(radius))

# girando e cortando a imagem para produzir amostras sinteticas
for j in range(1, POS_ROT_STEP):
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]

    rotated = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, -(360 / POS_ROT_STEP) * j, 1.0)

    nx = img.shape[1]
    ny = img.shape[0]

    rotated[0, 2] += (nx / 2) - x
    rotated[1, 2] += (ny / 2) - y

    output_aux = cv2.warpAffine(gray, rotated, (nx, ny))
    backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(output_aux,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    cv2.imwrite('~/rotate/'+IMG+'-'+str( j )+'.png', backtorgb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após a conversão para cinza, você perde todas as informações de cores **BGR**. Então não é possível realizar a conversão de cinza para colorido.

O que acontece quando você converte de **escala de cinza** para **BGR** com `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` é a criação de 3 canais, mas todos com valores iguais. Pois estava em escala de cinza.

#### Exemplo

Um pixel que possua o seguinte valor em escala de cinza: `(127)`, após a conversão possuirá três canais: `(127, 127, 127)`

### Alternativa

Uma alternativa para solucionar este problema é guardar uma cópia da imagem original com: `copia = img.copy()`

E depois de encontrar as coordenadas em **escala de cinza**, trabalhar em cima da imagem original.

### Observação

O espaço de cores padrão do OpenCV é **BGR**, então ao carregar a imagem com `img = cv2.imread(IMG+'.png')`, ela está no espaço de cores **BGR**.

Então a conversão `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` deveria ser `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: Usei o copy() e deu certo, obgdo